# Event-Handling with Windows API in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, winapi, event-handling

i am trying to implement my IDS Kamera with the `pyueye-libary`. Therefore i need multipel threads. One Monitoring-Thread(set Events) and a another one for the Capturing(wait till Events are set). The communication through Events.
The Camera-driver needs a Handle to a `WINAPI-Event`. Afterwards the Event need to initialized and enabled (this are functions from the pyueye-lib). For the Monitoring i am using WaitforSingleObject. I tired different kind of implementation of the Events. But i think the best method should be this:

```
hEvent_FL = win32event.CreateEvent(None, False, False, None)
hEvent_FL = int(hEvent_FL)
pEvent_FL=ueye.c_void_p(hEvent_FL)
```

So to get a `HANDLE` and not a `PyHANDLE` i need to convert into a `int` first.
For the Monitoring i use:

```
class inspect(Thread):
def __init__(self, point):
    super().__init__()
    self.point=point

def run(self):
    print("Trigger wartet")
    print(id(self.point))
    self.rc=ctypes.windll.kernel32.WaitForSingleObject(self.point, 5000)
    print(id(self.point))
    if self.rc == win32event.WAIT_TIMEOUT:
         print("TIMEOUT", self.rc)
         return self.rc
    elif self.rc == win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
         #ueye.is_CopyImageMem (h_cam, pcImgMem, nMemID, cam_mem.ctypes.data)
         print("WAIT_OBJECT_0")
         return self.rc
         #time.sleep(2)
    elif self.rc == win32event.WAIT_FAILED:
         print("WAIT_FAILED", self.rc)
         return self.rc
```

When i run this code it always raises `TIMEOUT`.


At the moment i am not sure if the converting of the HANDLE the may Problem and i don't have any clue what to do to debug this, cause i am not that advanced in multiprocessing for WINAPI in Python. Normally the `WaitForSingleObject` function should raise a `long`-statement but its a `int`. 
Can somebody help me or any advice how to check if i am using the right HANDLE?
 Thank you a lot!

Comment: If you get `WAIT_TIMEOUT`, you have a correct handle (although the conversions look fishy). Had you passed an invalid handle, you'd get an error instead. The real question now is: Why do you expect to *not* receive a timeout?

Comment: okay - thank you </br> So i have a Triggersignal which works(IO-Card - tested it). This Signal runs with 5 Hz so i am expecting to receive a WAIT_OBJECT_0 statement. perhaps i should post my whole code.